# Error in connecting django with mongodb: ImportError: No module named django.auth

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to create a blog using django and mongodb in aws ec2 instance

And in the file models.py, I am making following changes

```
from datetime import datetime
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Post(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    text = StringField(required=True)
    text_length = IntField()
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    is_published = BooleanField()

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Post(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    text = StringField(required=True)
    text_length = IntField()
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    is_published = BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.text_length = len(self.text)
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', args=[self.id])

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return reverse('update', args=[self.id])

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('delete', args=[self.id])
```

And, I get this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "models.py", line 7, in <module>
        from mongoengine.django.auth import User 
ImportError: No module named django.auth
```

And, in settings.py file, I am making following changes

```
import os
from mongoengine import *
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['54.149.63.203', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
'LJblog',
'django_extensions',
'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'LJ.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'LJ.wsgi.application'




DATABASES = {
 'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
'PASSWORD': '',
'HOST': '55.181.26.33', //mongodb ip address
'PORT': '27017',
    }
}



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)


TEMPLATE = (
 os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'
MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'
MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = 'LJ_blog'
from mongoengine import connect
connect(MONGO_DATABASE_NAME)
```

So, how can I resolve the import error?

Comment: Did you run syncdb command?

Comment: @rkatkam, I guess syncdb has been deprecated and replaced by migrate, so I didn't use syncdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django support was removed from MongoEngine in 0.10.0. You might be able to get an earlier version to work, but it might not support recent versions of Django.

With mongoengine 0.10 we can see that

> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/

will not have django package in it. 
Install mongoengine 0.9 using

> sudo pip install mongoengine==0.9

and the django package (support or extension) will be available.

Comment: that works and along with that we have to do this pip uninstall pymongo
 pip install pymongo==2.8
Otherwise there is some more error,do you have any idea how to deal this without MongoEngine?

Comment: actually pymongo also has some version issues with recent version of pymongo so we need to downgrade it to 2.8 I think not sure though.